# Passing QString from one QDialog's TextEdit to another QDialog after clicking a button

Tags: c++, qt, return

I'm using Qt Creator. Programming in C++.

I'm writing a program that will be used to learn words and expressions in English. I have the main window and 4 buttons there. After pressing one of them called "Test" I open a new QDialog to choose a category and after that and after pressing a button in that QDialog I want to run a test with 10 questions - every question is a new QDialog with one Text Edit/Text Browser to print the word/expression to translate and one Text Edit, where the user will be able to type in the answer. After pressing a button I would like to pass the typed answer to the previous QDialog class, where I would compare it with the expected answer and add or not a point for that question.

I tried doing it with a public function in the second QDialog class and using it in the first QDialog, but after pressing the button nothing happened. And if the function is private and activated after clicking the button, it won't pass the value back to first QDialog. I think I might use Signals/Slots, but I have no idea how to do it. I'm not very familiar with object programming and want to learn, but cannot understand how to use QObject::connect and I don't even know if I should.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What exactly were you expecting to happen when the button was pressed? was the buttons "clicked" signal connected to any slot?

Comment: Okay, I managed to solve that, don't know if there is a better way, but I guess it's not that bad: In the second QDialog, after pressing the button I do only that: `accept();` but there is also a public function [1st] and then in the first QDialog [2nd]: http://pastebin.com/WNx51cYw

Comment: That's probably the simplest solution